# Why is this.$router undefined in App.vue?

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue.js app with multiple components some of which use the router in a way like this:

```
    this.$router.push({
      name: 'overview',
      params: { ... },
    });
```

but if I try to do the same in App.vue:

```
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
    import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
    import store from './store/index';

    Vue.use(Vuetify);
    Vue.use(VueRouter);

    require('./components/vue-flash-message/FlashMessage.css');

    export default new Vue({
        async mounted() {
            ...
            this.$router.push({ name: 'overview' });
            ...
        },
    }).$mount('#app');
```

I get 'Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'. Is it possible to access it here?

The callstack is

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    App.vue:49
        at Vue._callee2$ (....WebUI\src\App.vue:49:1)
        at tryCatch (http://localhost:8080/app.js:5728:40)
        at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (http://localhost:8080/app.js:5962:22)
        at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (http://localhost:8080/app.js:5780:21)
        at step (http://localhost:8080/app.js:5458:30)
        at http://localhost:8080/app.js:5476:14
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at new F (http://localhost:8080/app.js:7082:28)
        at http://localhost:8080/app.js:5455:12
        at Vue.mounted (.....\WebUI\src\App.vue:47:1)
```

**EDIT1:**

If I do this

```
import router from './router/index';
```

and then refer the router as 'router' but not 'this.$router':

```
    export default new Vue({
        async mounted() {
            ...
            router.push({ name: 'overview' });
            ...
        },
    }).$mount('#app');
```

it works.

Comment: @Bert the same effect if it is directly in mounted() or inside a function. And the same effect with created().

Comment: @Bert Probably something unexpected is happening. It is directly in mounted() and I can see in the debugger that it is undefined.

Comment: I had a very similar situation where a function I have originally worked just fine, and after I tweaked a bunch of other components, Vue compiler all of a sudden complains about `'this' is undefined`.
The original function looked like this:
`<script setup>function goBack(){ this.$router.go(-1); }</script>`
I ended up doing what you seem to have originally done; I imported the router object from `router/index.js`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to configure a router and add it to the top-level component.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: ...
});


export default new Vue({
  router, // <-
  async mounted() {
    ...
```

Comment: What about doing "import router from './router/index';" instead of const router = new...?

Comment: To keep the routing logic is a separate file is even better, but you'll need to place that as the `router` property on the App component.

Comment: Why the root component behaves differently? And why 'router' was defined in other components without your changes?

Comment: 1. This allows you can have multiple routers on the same page. 2. The other components are child-components of a component that has the `router` property.